# Fetch every row of JSON data generated in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, json

This is a tough one, at least for me. So basically what I want to do is to get every single value of each row of this JSON data, via Javascript:

```
{"id":2,"url":"image.png","x":19,"y":10,"user_id":20}
{"id":3,"url":"image.png","x":19,"y":10,"user_id":20}
{"id":4,"url":"image.png","x":19,"y":10,"user_id":20}
{"id":5,"url":"image.png","x":19,"y":10,"user_id":20}
{"id":6,"url":"image.png","x":19,"y":10,"user_id":20}
{"id":7,"url":"image.png","x":19,"y":10,"user_id":20}
{"id":8,"url":"image.png","x":19,"y":10,"user_id":20}
{"id":9,"url":"image.png","x":19,"y":10,"user_id":20}
{"id":10,"url":"image.png","x":19,"y":10,"user_id":20}
{"id":31,"url":"image.png","x":19,"y":10,"user_id":20}
{"id":32,"url":"image.png","x":19,"y":10,"user_id":20}
{"id":33,"url":"image.png","x":19,"y":10,"user_id":20}
{"id":34,"url":"image.png","x":19,"y":10,"user_id":20}
{"id":35,"url":"image.png","x":19,"y":10,"user_id":20}
{"id":36,"url":"image.png","x":19,"y":10,"user_id":20}
{"id":37,"url":"image.png","x":19,"y":10,"user_id":20}
{"id":38,"url":"image.png","x":19,"y":10,"user_id":20}
{"id":39,"url":"image.png","x":19,"y":10,"user_id":20}
{"id":40,"url":"image.png","x":19,"y":10,"user_id":20}
```

I generated it this way (in my PHP file):

```
$db->where('user_id', '20');
$results = $db->get('profile_stickers');

foreach ($results as $parameters => $values) { 
       echo json_encode($values);
}
```

I've tried with a lot of codes related to jQuery's `$.each` but no luck, the code never works. I want to get every value because then I am going to display them on a page, with the right position, and image. Does anyone know the proper function to fetch every single row? Like PHP's `$row['foo']`.

----- EDIT ------

I did it like this:

```
$.get('/Application/Ajax/__ajaxProfile.php?a=GetWidgets', function(data) {

var json = data;

for (i=0;i<json.length;i++){
    var obj = json[i];
    for (var key in obj) {
        document.getElementById("log").innerHTML += key+": "+obj[key]+"<br />";
    }
    document.getElementById("log").innerHTML += "<br />";
} 

});
```

But the problem is, it returns data like this:

0: "
0: [
0: { 
0: i
0: d
etc..

---- EDIT -----

Fixed now, it was the "$.get" thingy.

Comment: This is not a valid JSON.

Comment: When generating JSON from PHP, you should only ever call `json_encode` *once*!  Generate the structure you want, then call `json_encode` at the very end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be what you want.

```
$db->where('user_id', '20');
$results = $db->get('profile_stickers');

$arr = array();

foreach ($results as $parameters => $values) {

    $arr[] = $values;

}

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what you're looking for, but this is a way to get through everything once it's in javascript.

You'll basically need to store that as an array of JSON objects:

```
var json = [
{"id":2,"url":"image.png","x":19,"y":10,"user_id":20},
{"id":3,"url":"image.png","x":19,"y":10,"user_id":20},
...etc
]
```

You can then loop through the array and objects like this:

```
for (i=0;i<json.length;i++){
  var obj = json[i];
  for (var key in obj) {
    document.write(key+": "+obj[key]);
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Y4uAx/